# GZIP without using IIS?

Tags: iis, dynamic, compression

I was wondering whether anyone knew of any ASP.NET compression modules that can use GZIP without relying on the IIS dynamic compression module ?

We have some content which we want serve up as GZIPPED but we dont want to rely on IIS compression.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: hi thanks all for the great responses :) Not sure - but I found this - http://code.google.com/p/httpcompress/ - is this the best one or are there others?

Answer (score 2):

A good one

[Building a GZip JavaScript Resource Compression Module for ASP.NET](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/10294.aspx)

Comment: hi - basically we serve some JS files - dynamic and static - and we want to render them in either GZIP or DEFLATE - is the module pasted above pretty good to do this or without using IIS?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in code the [.NET 7Zip library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/) supports GZip compression.  You could write an HTTPModule ot HTTPHandler that wraps the 7Zip compression library and handle this in code.